# Collapse JSON object with jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq, flatten

I'm having trouble completing the last piece of this puzzle. I want to flatten a JSON that contains an array with jq. Current Progress: https://jqplay.org/s/fwjTN1CnFc

Input:

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "list": 
    [
        {
            "Key": "b",
            "Value": "2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "c",
            "Value": "3"
        },
        {
            "Key": "d",
            "Value": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "3",
  "d": "4"
}
```

Here is a link to my current progress. https://jqplay.org/s/fwjTN1CnFc

I am currently using this query `{a: .a},  (.list | map({(.Key): .Value}) | add)`

And here are my currently incorrect results that I can't quite get right:

```
{
  "a": "1"
}
{
  "b": "2",
  "c": "3",
  "d": "4"
}
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens, your .list is exactly suited to jq's `from_entries`, so you can simply write:

```
{a} + (.list|from_entries)
```

Your approach, however, can easily be made to work:

```
{a} +  (.list | map({(.Key): .Value}) | add)
```

Comment: ah! obviously a newbie here, missing the concatenation. That from_entries is extremely handy. Thanks!